# Lock var and force other thread to wait

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I try to force my thread to wait the unlock of one var

In my infinite game loop

```
notifyObserver();
lock.lock();
try {

} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

In observer

```
public void actualize() {
     lock.lock();
     ...
}
```

Button Action code

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        _game.setCategory(button.getCategory());
        lock.unlock();
    }
});
```

I have tried that but it's doesn't work. I have one observer.

I have more experience in c++, maybe it's not a good way to tried to lock var like that.

Comment: not fully understand your whole logic. but I think you'd better use the lock in a single class to protect the share resource rather than putting a lock everywhere.

Comment: the var lock is shared between all of my class

Comment: Why the asymmetry? why lock the lock in the observer and unlock it in the action listener?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).